# How to represent responses with heterogenous arrays in pact-jvm

Tags: pact, pact-jvm

I'm having trouble figuring out how to represent arrays with structurally different objects in an array in pact contracts.

From [pact-spec-v3](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-specification/tree/version-3)

> It would also be required to define whether the matchers should be
>   combined with logical AND (all matchers must match) or OR (at least
>   one matcher must match). AND should be the default, but there are
>   cases where an OR makes sense

Can this be leveraged to 'OR' the two different types of objects ?

This is the response that I'm trying to model via the pact-jvm DSL, the `suggestions` array contains two objects of different types, '1' and '3', having different schemas -

```
{
  "suggestions": [
    {
      "display_name": "Potato",
      "type": 1,
      "keyword": "Potato",
      "category_l1": {
        "icon_image_url": "XXXXX",
        "id": 1489,
        "name": "Potato"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": 3,
      "suggestion": {
        "display_name": "New Potato (Aloo)",
        "name": "New Potato"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Code that I have so far:

```
private DslPart getBody() {
    return new PactDslJsonBody()
            .eachLike("suggestions", 1)
                    .stringType("display_name")
                    .integerType("type")
                    .stringType("keyword")
                    .object("category_l1")
                        .stringType("icon_image_url")
                        .stringType("name")
                        .integerType("id")
                    .closeObject()
                    .closeObject()
            .closeArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently easy to model with Pact, it works assuming each item is similar to a provided example. For a discussion, see https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-specification/issues/38